# Does db_ddladmin have reader and writer permission in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

DDLadmin has privilege's to alter the objects like schema, permissions. But my question is, does db_dlladmin has permission to read (db_datareader) and write (db_datawriter) in database.

Does db_datareader and db_datawriter are subsets of DDLadmin role?

Comment: This is totally false

Comment: There's a convenient diagram of the [built-in permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15#fixed-database-roles) in the documentation that states "The other database level permissions are not granted to any fixed database role except db_owner"

Answer (score 0):

By security reason, the Microsoft SQL Server db_ddladmin only can ALTER, CREATE and DROP. It cannot SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE nor MERGE or TRUNCATE.

Demo...

```
CREATE USER USR_DDL WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO

ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER USR_DDL
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'USR_DDL'

SELECT *
FROM   anytable
```

Error wil result !